# How curl provided source code that the browser did not?

Tags: source-code, curl

I was playing a CTF and got stuck. When seeing the source code through web browser reveals nothing but when we send the request through `curl` it reveals out HIDDEN directory. How is it even possible? Does that mean we should now double check the source code by using `curl` too?

Comment: Without an example, it will be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers and `curl` should provide the same code, unless the server inspects the headers (like for the user-agent string) and sends the different code to different clients that connect.

This is not uncommon when trying to create a complex site that does not render well on older browsers. But in a CTF, it's a simple way to show completely different info to different browsers/clients.

Comment: Means in CTF, it is very easy to set the response on User-agent based. If it found CURL then it will present a different page? BTW sorry for my bad presentation. :)

Comment: yes, it inspect the user-agent string. It's very easy to deliver different content based on user-agent string even outside of a CTF.

Comment: It might not even be UA-based but based on some other property.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the clarification. Really for once, I was really worried about this.